# Android Prevent Notification if in desired Activity

Tags: android, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How can I get the current foreground activity (from a service)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873659/android-how-can-i-get-the-current-foreground-activity-from-a-service)
>   [Optionally starting activities and using notifications from services in Android. Only launch or notify if a certain app is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762192/optionally-starting-activities-and-using-notifications-from-services-in-android)

If I produce a notification when I get an update in my SyncService, how do I prevent it from appearing if I am already in the activity that uses the new information?

It's kind of like when you use the gmail app, a notification will come when you are outside of the app, but you never see it when you are in it.

Comment: Also see http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CommonsWare provides a solution to this as an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873659/android-how-can-i-get-the-current-foreground-activity-from-a-service).

Specifically, he links to [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html), which explains the use of ordered broadcasts.

As a not-so-efficient idea, you could implement a broadcast receiver in your activity and service, then before sending the notification, send a broadcast intent to your activity and wait for a response.  If you don't get a response, raise the notification.